# Search for all instances of foo(Bar.class)

Tags: java, eclipse

Does eclipse have an easy way to search for all invocations of a method based on the type of the argument(s)? For example if `a` and `b` are instance of `Foo` and `x` and `y` are instances of `Bar`, I want to find `foo(x)` and `foo(y)` but not `foo(a)` or `foo(b)`.

Comment: can't you do a "Find all References > Workspace" for `foo(Bar bar)` ?

Comment: Do you mean type of the argument like if `subclass extends class`, then you want to find all calls of foo with say `subclass` object as argument or specific object of `subclass`, say `subClsObjA`?

Or else I guess Ctrl + Alt + H (Open Call hierarchy) helps.

Comment: @Bhushan Yeah, I want to find everywhere the method is called with a specific subclass.

Comment: I basically want Open Call Hierarchy limited to a specific subclass as an argument.

Comment: @Bala R I want to find `foo(Bar bazz)` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily declare an overloaded "fake" method foo with the specific types of parameters in which you are interested. All relevant invocations of the real foo should be resolved to the fake one. Then do a "Find all References" for the fake foo (before deleting it).

[EDIT]

This will work provided certain constraints regarding subclassing hold. Otherwise, you will get a superset of the invocations in which you are interested, which may still be narrow enough to be useful.

Comment: Ugly (especially since I have to modify an interface as well) but works! I was hoping there would be an easier way but this is a neat trick.